# Android SELinux: allow sys_ptrace for custom daemon

Tags: android, security, selinux

I am writing daemon for LineageOS which must be able to monitor running processes. But when I have started build I have run into SEPolicy neverallows. Investigating further sepolicy I have found the following rule in `system/sepolicy/private/domain.te`:

```
neverallow {
  domain
  -vold
  userdebug_or_eng(`-llkd')
  -dumpstate
  userdebug_or_eng(`-incidentd')
  -storaged
  -system_server
} self:global_capability_class_set sys_ptrace;
```

Is it possible to somehow bypass this rule without changing code of LineageOS system sepolicy. I have tried the following:

```
type valord, coredomain, domain;
type valor_db, file_type;
type valord_exec, exec_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(valord)
domain_auto_trans(init, valord_exec, valord)

# NOFIX: The valord do not detects proccess when it 
# is not given sys_ptrace capability. Since is is
# in neverallow's we have no way but to rewrite neverallow

neverallow {
  domain
  -valord 
  -vold
  userdebug_or_eng(`-llkd')
  -dumpstate
  userdebug_or_eng(`-incidentd')
  -storaged
  -system_server
} self:global_capability_class_set sys_ptrace;

# ...
# Some allow's that are verified to pass
# ..
allow valord self:global_capability_class_set sys_ptrace;
```

but it still failed with the error that my policy violates above mentioned `neverallow` in `system/sepolicy/private/domain.te`

**P.S.:** The denial message is: `11-12 01:06:22.582  3369  3369 W valord  : type=1400 audit(0.0:71): avc: denied { sys_ptrace } for capability=19 scontext=u:r:valord:s0 tcontext=u:r:valord:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0`

Comment: Removing `domain` from `type` helps to build the ROM(probably because failing neverallow is written for `domain` type), but daemon does not start up with system and no messages about problem are available in driver messages or logcat.

Comment: What is/are the avc denial(s) exactly ?

Comment: Have just added it to question body, so everyone would be able to see.